# Urine on clothes

Tags: salat, wudu, fard

As Salam alaikum. Unfortunately, I suffer from prostatitis. And sometimes there are feelings as if urine has dripped, sometimes it happens that it's just an instigation, and it happens that it has dripped. And when I was in the toilet today, I was washing myself and this feeling happened. It was like urine dripped, but I do not know if it really dripped, and if it dripped, where exactly on clothes. Absolutely no idea. What to do?

Answer (score 2):

You are suffering from Waswas and you should not give much attention to any of the thoughts like "feelings as if urine has dripped" unless you see a concrete evidence.

The prophet [told](https://sunnah.com/nasai:160) someone who was suspecting his Wudu during the prayer: "Do not stop praying unless you notice a smell or hear a sound", i.e. if you suspect your wudu for some feeling, you ignore it and persist on praying unless you notice something evident.

Comment: to add to what you said, we have to understand that Allah is Afwun (Pardoning), so we just try to avoid urine, finally if some drops of urine happened to be there, he may pardon us.